# my Pivotal cloud foundry app is crashing often while doing healthcheck

Tags: spring-boot, pcfdev

I have created a spring boot integration app and deployed it to Pivotal Cloud Foundry (PCF) environment. It works for couple of days and then it starts to crash randomly afterwards. I checked the PCF logs and found this information about the crash.

```
OUTApp instance exited with guid 3c348d47-48c4-403f-950a-29af1efa551d 
payload: {"instance"=>"e2122543-214f-4806-62c7-00e1", "index"=>2, 
"reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"Instance became unhealthy: Failed 
to make HTTP request to '/health' on port 8080: timed out after 1.00 
seconds", "crash_count"=>1, "crash_timestamp"=>1511959503256098495, 
"version"=>"10cea919-d490-460d-83d6-5132c96ef781"}
```

My CPU utilization is not much. My memory is also not leaking.

Information about the application deployed in PCF:
Spring boot integration app connects to IBM MQ queues and polls for messages and then calls couple of web services.

There is also another application Service Bus, which makes the health check call on PCF application to check if the PCF app is available or not. If Service Bus finds that PCF app is available then the requests are routed to PCF else they are processed at Service Bus end itself.

Please let me know, how to find the root cause of the CRASH and fix it.
Thanks in advance. Please let me know, if you need further details.

Comment: Same here. I'm using the health endpoint from the Spring Boot Actuator library for the http health check, the configuration in the manifest looks like this:  

`health-check-type: http  
health-check-http-endpoint: /health`  

There is a hard limit of one second in which this health endpoint has to respond, otherwise CF marks the app as crashed and the restart mechanism kicks in.  

That behavior should be improved, I think. Anybody from Pivotal reading this topic?

Comment: same here, but using dotnet buildpack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the health check type to port type from http in manifest.yml file. 
configuration change in manifest file is as follows:

**health-check-type: port**

Now the app is not crashing. It is working fine. Hope this helps.

Comment: is this a reported bug?